My router stop working after wireless upgrade
Model d-link dwr-m960
After wireless upgrade router stop working and emergency site not working but system repair open at ip 192.168.1.6 but still not working after upgrading with wired connection can you help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

how did you do the upgrade?
